# use a function inside another function in the same file with Node Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I would have a simple question but can't figure it out the answer with Node.JS. Here it is : I got a file with multiple function and I would like to use the return of the first inside the second :

```js
//The first function
const Function1 = (req, res) => {
    var axios = require('axios');
    var config = {
        method: 'get',
        url: 'xxxxx.json',
        headers: {
            //...
        }
    };
    axios(config).then(function(response) {
        const array = response.data.datas
        return Promise.all(Object.values(array).map(entry => {
            return entry.id
        }))
    }).then(function(response) {
        //I got an array with infos
        return response
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
const Function2 = (req, res) => {
    const previousResult = function1()
    //Undefined
    console.log(previousResult)
}
```

How should I proceed ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/438992

Comment: `Function1` doesn't have a `return` statement!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to call the function?

```
function1()
```

Update:

It looks like you added to your question. This now seems to be an issue with async functions. You should look up how to use promises, and async await. It's a bit too complex to describe here, and there are a lot of tutorials about it. The short answer is that when you return inside of a promise, it doesn't return from the outer function1. You could probably test this in your code by putting an explicit return at the end of function1 and you'll see that in console.log().

Comment: Thanks. when I `console.log(function1())` I got `undefined`

Comment: @ArthurFortin see my updated response